# Extract a list of Elastic IPs and Instance Names using AWS System Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

In the AWS Cloud Environment i have to the get list of all Elastic IPs with instance name and in all region/AZs like eu-west-1 , eu-west-3, ap-south-1, us-east-1 etc..

How this can be achieved via AWS System manager if possible. If not, then do i have to write any other function/code or use other AWS functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it by writing a program (eg in Python) with these steps:

- Loop through each (applicable) Region using [`describe_regions()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_regions)

  - Loop through each Elastic IP address using [`describe_addresses()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_addresses)

    - Extract the `InstanceId` and `PublicIp` from the response
    - Call [`describe_instances()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) for the given `InstanceId` to obtain a list of Tags. The "instance name" is stored as a Tag with `Key = 'Name'`

Comment: Thanks John for the reply. and i will have to use Boto3 for this?

Comment: I'm just saying that's how I would write it, since I'm a Python person. You could use any AWS SDK to do it, if you prefer a different language.

Comment: Ohk..Thanks John